# The scrobbler plugin stopped working in the Audacious player

Tags: last.fm

Clicking on the Check Permission results in the message "There was a problem contacting Last.fm. They will be submitted as soon as Audacious is allowed access." The Revoke Permission button does nothing. I don't know if this is a my device issue or a general plugin issue.

I reinstalled the player, looked for similar problems and recommendations, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue since December. Apparently there's a malformation in the XML sent by Last.FM. I'm trying to figure it out. If I'm able to fix it, I'll post later.

**UPDATE:** They fixed this issue the last month. I managed to make it work again here. I'm running ArchLinux and the audacious and audacious-plugins packages still outdated (2023), so I had to clone the latest version of audacious-plugin on GitHub, then compile only the "scrobbler2" plugin and replace it on my OS.

Source code for the plugins:

https://github.com/audacious-media-player/audacious-plugins

How do you compile it:

After cloning the repository, enter the directory below:

```
$ cd <cloned source dir>/src/scrobbler2
$ make
```

This will build the **scrobbler.so** file. Then all you have to do is replace the original with it. In the ArchLinux here, it was located on this path:

```
/usr/lib/audacious/General/scrobbler.so
```

Then it's back working again. Not a fashionable solution, but indeed, it works. =)

Comment: Thank you. Good luck with that. I'll be waiting for news about this.

Comment: I updated the answer, so good luck solving you issue there too. =)